# Error con xcode: Hace el building del proyecto contiinuamente y sin decirle nada

Tags: xcode

Tengo un error en xcode, Hace el building del proyecto contiinuamente y sin decirle nada

Os ha pasado a alguno?? Porque he estado buscando por internet pero no encuentro nada al respecto.

Al hacer continuamente el building, me consume muchios recursos y el xcode va muy lento

El error aparece cuando abro el `Main.storyboard`, cuando le quito, cierro el `xcode`, lo vuelvo a abrir y funciona correctamente

Mi version de `xcode`: 8.1 (8B62)

Comment: Supongo que ya has hecho un clean. Y también has probado a reiniciar el mac.

Comment: Sii, he probado todo. Cuando reinicio el mac se soluciona momentaneamente pero al poco vuelve a dar error @MarcLemien

Comment: Aquí hay uno con el mismo problema. Puedes desabilitar el auto build en preferencias. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434968/how-do-you-disable-auto-build-in-xcode